# How to run python commands from flutter using tcp socket

Tags: python, flutter, dart, sockets, tcp

Im trying to send commands to a python script from flutter using tcp sockets. In python Im using the pyzmq library.

**Python:**

```
import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5556")

while True:
    #  Wait for next request from client
    print('Listening...')
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received request: %s" % message)

    #  Do some 'work'
    time.sleep(1)

    #  Send reply back to client
    socket.send(b"World")
```

I then send messages to the python receiver using flutter but nothing is getting received or printed out in python. Simplified code below:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

socket = await Socket.connect('localhost', 5556);
socket.add(utf8.encode('hello'));
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: as I know `zmq` is more complex then normal `socket` and you can't send `hello` to `zmq`. You may have to send special structure with data.

Comment: @furas Yes its confusing. In  the docs for the dart version of zmq  a message is sent simply by `socket.send([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);`  I couldnt get zmq for dart to work so I used `Socket` instead. The line `utf8.encode('hello')` is simply converting hello to `[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]`

Comment: what documentation? I found example which doesn't use standard Socket but has to use special module for `zmq`

Comment: [Send messages to ZeroMQ server using conventional TCP, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246921/send-messages-to-zeromq-server-using-conventional-tcp-possible)

Comment: doc for dart and flutter: [ZMQ](https://zeromq.org/languages/dart/) and module [dartzmq](https://pub.dev/packages/dartzmq/example)

Comment: @furas Thanks for the links, has made me understand the cases where zmq is useful. I did try using the `dartzmq` but I couldnt get it working as there is a difficult step of creating some dll file. Yes you are right zmq is more complex, I think I will just stick with the normal sockets implementation in python as it seems to be working great for simple requests and responses